# How does __(Dexterity) vs. AC work?

Tags: dnd-4e, attack-roll, armor-class

I'm working through the new Red Box, and have ended up with a character with the at-will `Bump And Run` power.

The attack is listed as

> __ (Dexterity) vs. AC

Is this just a straight comparison of the players dexterity vs the monster's AC?

Comment: Actually, I think in the Players Manual for the Red Box it talks about writing down values on the cards, so that's probably just a space to write the Dexterity modifier.

Comment: This syntax is found in non-Esssentials work, its not essentials specific.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For

> Attack: Dexterity vs. AC

you roll `1d20` and add your bonuses (using your Dexterity modifier) and compare that to the monster's AC.

If the sum is equal to or greater than the monster's AC, the monster is hit with the power.

Your bonuses are 1/2 your level + the attribute modifier (in this case Dex) + other bonuses such as weapon proficiency(+2), a weapon's magical enhancement bonus, feat bonuses, and circumstantial bonuses.

See the definition for `Attack` and `Attack Roll`.

Comment: So glad someone answered this, but I'm also confused on this subject. The character sheet tells you to add your attack bonus which in my case is +7 with a dagger. So when would I add that? Or is it when you use an ability, you use your dexterity modifier instead of attack bonus.

Comment: Hey @Mike! Check out the question [How do you determine your attack?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7893/how-do-you-determine-your-attack) for another description (and page references).

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the selected answer is correct.
The syntax of

> __ (Dexterity) vs. AC

In the red box means, if you have a Dex of say 18, you would fill in the __ with +4.  So the final card should read

> *+4* (Dexterity) vs. AC

In this particular attack, you do not add the +3 or +2 from your weapon proficiency, but you do add your half a level.

So if you charachter has 18 dex, then you would roll a 1d20, add 4 and then compare that to the AC value of the monster.

Comment: Isn't bump and run a weapon attack? So don't you add your proficiency after all?