# How do you determine your attack?

Tags: dnd-4e, attack-roll

For instance: a spell says "Int vs AC" Do you roll raw int + d20 vs AC?

Do you roll Int bonus + d20 vs AC?

Do you roll int bonus+weapon accuracy +d20 vs AC?  (This is a question about swordmage, so I have a melee weapon AND cast spells)

Please help.  We've been confused on this and it seems like it'd be pretty crazy to just take int bonus +d20

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does __(Dexterity) vs. AC work?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4298/how-does-dexterity-vs-ac-work)

Comment: I don't think it's a dupe, the other one seems mostly confusion about the __ before (Dexterity) in the red box. This one has a more generic title as well.

Comment: One of the most helpful things our group has done is get a DDI subscription, it generates character sheets with power cards all of the to hit and damage modifiers included right on the power cards. Its about 10$ a month if you go month to month or cheaper if you buy a whole year at a time.

Answer (score 12):

How to make attack rolls is described on pages 215-7 of the *Rules Compendium* in pretty good detail.  To sum it up.  The *Player's Handbook* has a smaller version on page 274.

**When making an attack roll add the following to 1d20:**

1. The modifier for the attack power the character is using.  This will be a stat bonus + 1/2 of the character's level.
2. The permanent modifiers to the attack.

   - Magic weapon bonus
   - Proficiency bonus
   - Feat bonuses
3. The temporary modifiers to the attack.

   - Combat Advantage
   - Cover
   - Concealment

Ideally a player should know the sum of #1-2 for each power they possess.  Then they'd only need to handle the temporary modifiers.

Comment: Thanks!   Didn't read the PHB cover to cover must have missed that page.

Comment: We actually have one player with ddi sub and he prints out our powercadds and such.  But I was confused about the exact calcs

Comment: @Ben - don't worry about it.  D&D 4e is a pretty complex system.  We all miss stuff.  Also, welcome to the site!

Comment: @Ben - If this answers your question, consider marking it as the accepted answer using the check mark under the up/down vote.